# How to access sklearn's KDE params for scipy's Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, kernel-density, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a 1-D discrete dataset. On this set, I want to perform a kernel density estimation with sklearn's built-in function:

```
from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity

data = ... # array of shape [5000, 1]

## perform kde with gaussian kernels
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.8).fit(data.reshape(-1, 1))
```

With help from kde's instance method `score_samples`, I am able to plot a reasonable estimation of the underlying density function:

[image: pdf created with kde]

```
## code for plot
X_plot = np.linspace(-5, 100, 10000)[:, np.newaxis]
log_dens = kde.score_samples(X_plot)

plt.plot(X_plot[:, 0], np.exp(log_dens))
```

I want to use this distribution to perform a one-sample KS-test. I found that scipy already implements this functionality. Check the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html). It says:

> **scipy.stats.kstest(rvs, cdf, args=(), N=20, alternative='two-sided', mode='approx')**
>
> rvs : str, array or callable
>
> If a string, it should be the name of a distribution in scipy.stats.
> If an array, it should be a 1-D array of observations of random
> variables. If a callable, it should be a function to generate random
> variables; it is required to have a keyword argument size.
>
> cdf : str or callable
>
> If a string, it should be the name of a distribution in scipy.stats. If rvs is a string then cdf can be False or the same as
> rvs. If a callable, that callable is used to calculate the cdf.

Basically, rvs is the new sample data and cdf is the cumulative distribution function (integral of the pdf). I was not able to find out how to access the function that calculates the pdf within sklearn, so that I can integrate it and feed it to the kstest.

Has anybody an idea how to get there? Also, if there are any alternatives to this approach, please let me know.

Comment: KDE is a method for estimating the pdf of some data. According to the docs, the `score_samples` method evaluates the log density, by which they mean the log of the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply integrate `score_samples` to obtain the cdf.  [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad) might work.

** EDIT ** It seems that `score_samples` is the log density but when un-logged integrates to 1.  Does need some reshaping though, and the scipy integration bounds don't accept arrays unfortunately.

```
def cdf(y):
    return functools.partial(
        scipy.integrate.quad,
        lambda x: np.exp(kde.score_samples(np.array([x]).reshape(-1,1)))[0],
        -np.inf
    )(y)[0]

def array_cdf(X):
    return np.array(list(map(cdf, X)))

scipy.stats.kstest(data, array_cdf)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but ``score_samples`` is just a functionality to evaluate the hidden estimate at certain points. I am not sure if this is a valid function that can be integrated. I have edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: Is it defined at all `x`?  If so, it can be integrated.